# How to detect logged of any website visited in webview using react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, cookies, webview

I am trying to check if a user is logged in or not on an e-commerce website and to do so I was trying to get the cookie details using webview. Below is my approach, however, I am not getting any cookies.

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import CookieManager from 'react-native-cookies';

const App = () => {
  const [cookies, setCookies] = useState('');

  const onNavigationStateChange = (event) => {
    if (
      event.url ===
      'https://www.example.com'
    ) {
      CookieManager.get(event.url).then((cookies) => {
        setCookies(cookies);
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.example.com' }}
      onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
    />
  );
};
```